# How is interpreted an enum type with EF Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Here is a model:

```
Public class Person
{
    [Key]
    Public int PersonId { get; set: }
    Public int Age { get; set; }
    Public ColorEnum FavoriteColor { get; set; }
}

Public Enum ColorEnum
{
    Red = 1,
    Green = 2,
    Blue = 3
}
```

Is it possible for Entity Framework Code First to use the Person model to generate the corresponding table? What about the ColorEnum type?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EF 4.3 doesn't support Enums. But is has been announced that [`Enum` support is coming with EF 5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-released.aspx), which is due out alongside .NET 4.5. To handle enums with Code-First currently you'll do something like the following:

```
Public class Person
{
    [Key]
    Public int PersonId { get; set: }
    Public int Age { get; set; }

    public int FavoriteColorValue{ get; set;}
    [NotMapped]
    Public ColorEnum FavoriteColor 
    { 
        get{ return (ColorEnum)FavoriteColorValue; } 
        set{ FavoriteColorValue = (int)value; } 
    }
}

Public Enum ColorEnum
{
    Red = 1,
    Green = 2,
    Blue = 3
}
```

Comment: You should decorate FavoriteColor with NotMappedAttribute to ensure compatibility when upgrading to EF5+. If not, you may find you end up with both columns in your database.