# enum with different value in context vs. UnitOfWork

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, enums

I have a "little" problem with ASP.NET MVC 3 and enum:

My Person Model:

```
namespace AcTIV.Models
{
    public enum Sex { Male, Female };

    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Sex Sexo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Initializer:

```
namespace AcTIV.DAL
{
    public class AcTIVInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<AcTIVContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(AcTIVContext context)
        {    
            var persons = new List<Person>
            {
                new Person { Name = "Mary Lee", Sexo = Sex.Female }
            };
            persons.ForEach(s => context.Persons.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

So far, so good. My Watch displays the correct values.

```
persons[0].Name = "Mary Lee"  
persons[0].Sexo = Female
```

Now, my Person Controller:

```
namespace AcTIV.Controllers
{
    public class PersonController : Controller
    {
        private UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            Person person = unitOfWork.PersonRepository.GetByID(1); //Just for test
            //return View(unitOfWork.PersonRepository.Get().ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

Here my Watch displays the wrong enum value:

```
person.Name = "Mary Lee"  
person.Sexo = Male
```

What am I doing wrong?

--- SOLVED ---

The Answer is on another stackoverflow post: 
[How is interpreted an enum type with EF Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9418958/890645)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using EF4.3? I believe `enum` support is only available in EF5

Comment: Yes, Entity Framework 4.3.1. I think you're right with the non-support for this version. I'll try to have a confirmation.

Comment: Thanks for taking me to the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9418958/890645

Answer (score 0):

My doubt is that the Sex enum value for Person with ID in the PersonRepository is not set correctly. By default the first enumerator have a value of 0

But in Mary Lee's Person record looks like it is going as Male = 0 instead of Female = 1

Comment: One more thing, if I define Sex nullable (public Sex? Sexo {get;set;}), the PersonRepository returns the null value

Comment: Given that I cannot see your PersonRepository Code I would say that your not using sex.GetValueOrDefault()